# IE11: document.getSelection not working properly inside Input (i.e. text) tags on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to get the selection inside an input html tag using document.getSelection() but it doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11. The function is supported but the value returned seems wrong.

I tested it on Chrome and Edge and it work well so it seems that the issue is related with IE11.

On Chrome and Edge it returns a selection object with values on anchorNode and rangeCount (different to 0), and it shows the selected text when the toString() function is called. When nothing is selected or the input is empty but it is focused, it still has values on anchorNode and rangeCount but the toString function returns an empty string.

Chrome:

https://media.giphy.com/media/mFpXA8uv0GwUEx6Ofu/giphy.gif
https://i.postimg.cc/ncnM5QtP/chrome-abc-selection.png

IE11:

https://media.giphy.com/media/mFpXA8uv0GwUEx6Ofu/giphy.gif
https://i.postimg.cc/QxSVrx8x/IE11-abc-selection.png

I'm mainly need a value on rangeCount property that getSelection() returns because then I need to call the getRange function but I'm dealing with it, I'm having issues with IE11 and I need to make the site compatible with all those browsers.

Is this an IE11 bug that can be fixed by Microsoft or is there a workaround I can implement?

Comment: Note that it's actually a Chrome bug. Selection should disregard form controls. Their implementation makes things very weird btw, if you try so select that input and other text in the page, then it will disregard the input's value...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML DOM element to get the selection indexes via element.selectionStart and element.selectionEnd, then you just get the value of the element and do a substring on the value using the indexes....see example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Show me My Selection</button> 
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="This is my selection"><br>
<script>
 myFunction = function(){
    let element = document.getElementById("myInput");
    alert('The selected text = ' + element.value.substring(element.selectionStart,element.selectionEnd));  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```